# Failed to render and update autolayout status library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a XIB file that doesn't use autolayout but I get the error:

> file:///Users/..../Base.lproj/VCVideoCallScreen.xib:
>   error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status
>   for ESView (MNu-29-beS): dlopen(StaticLibs.framework, 1): Library not
>   loaded: @rpath/TwilioChatClient.framework/TwilioChatClient
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/.../IBDesignables/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TwilioChatLibs.framework/TwilioChatLibs
>   Reason: image not found

The TwilioChatLib framework is included in a framework from which certain objects used in the xib file are instantiated... 
Mention: cocoapods is not in use in this project.
Any ideas how to go about this?